# Redirect URLs with Leading ? (Question Mark) to new URLs

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, joomla

I have a list of 301 Redirects from our old site to our new Joomla site that are required.

The old url form is "www.domain.com/?library/etc/etc" and the corresponding new URL is completely different.  Is there a way to set up the .htaccess file to handle these, so I can simply then do my list, e.g.,

```
Redirect 301 /?library/home /index.php?option=com_zoo&view=frontpage&layout=frontpage&Itemid=183
```

If not, what's the best way to handle these redirects?  They don't currently work in the .htaccess, nor do they appear to work within the Joomla Redirect component.

thanks,
Geoff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't match against the query string (the `?` and the stuff after it) in a `Redirect` or a `RewriteRule`. You need to match against the `%{QUERY_STRING}` variable in a `RewriteCond`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^library/home$
RewriteRule ^$ /index.php?option=com_zoo&view=frontpage&layout=frontpage&Itemid=183 [L,R=301]
```

etc.

Comment: Thanks Jon. That seems to work, but only if I include the fully qualified domain in the redirect.  Is there a way to preserve the query string parameters that might appear in the old url after the first one.  i.e., lose the first /?key, but retain the rest, having them appended to the redirection?